# When loading QWORD from address ~~111xxx refers multiple cache blocks?

Tags: cpu-cache

For instance, assume there is a QWORD starting from address *~~111100*.
*111100+8* is *1000100* which increments the set index bit(since block offset is 6 bit), so I think it means it is not saved in the single cache block.
Does this means that the CPU should refer 2 cache blocks?

Comment: Yes, assuming a cache block is 64-byte in size.

Comment: Oh... thanks for your answer